# A better way to combine RAC signals to disable UI controls

Tags: swift, swift2, reactive-cocoa

I'm using Swift 2.1 and ReactiveCocoa 4.0.4 alpha 1. I'm trying to combine multiple signals and enable a button based on if they have valid inputs. The following code works correctly, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant and efficient way of accomplishing this with the ReactiveCocoa APIs, as well as if this is the proper way to be using the API in Swift.

```
    let sig0 = firstTextField.rac_textSignal()
        .max(self.firstTextField, max: maxLength)
        .map{ next in
            if let str = next as? String {
                return str.characters.count > 0
            } else {
                return false
            }
    }

    let sig1 = secondTextField.rac_textSignal()
        .max(self.secondTextField, max: maxLength)
        .map{ next in
            if let str = next as? String {
                return str.characters.count > 0
            } else {
                return false
            }
    }

    let combined = RACSignal.combineLatest([sig0, sig1])
    combined.subscribeNext { (obj: AnyObject!) -> Void in
        let tup = obj as! RACTuple
        let valid = (tup.first as! Bool) && (tup.second as! Bool)
        self.button.enabled = valid
    }
```

Comment: This is good enough except that you are using Objective-C APIs

Comment: @Cosyn What would be the correct Swift APIs I should be using? I'm new to Swift and have some experience with ReactiveCocoa which is why I went straight to this API

Comment: There is ready-to-use framework for controlling UIKit over ReactiveCocoa  https://github.com/neilpa/Rex/, you could use it or just grab the code you need (https://github.com/neilpa/Rex/blob/master/Source/UIKit/UIControl.swift).

Comment: @skyylex Very helpful, thanks!